# play - try to implements Writes to List[Any]

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a case class that looks like this:

case class A(name: String, values: List[Any])
While values can be a list of long or string.

I am trying to implement a Writes without success. 
This the code I have:

```
implicit val myWrites: Writes[A] = (
(JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "values").write[JsArray].contramap[List[Any]](
    (list: List[Any]) => list match{
    case longs: List[Long] => JsArray(longs.map(l => JsNumber(l)))
    case strings: List[String] => JsArray(strings.map(s => JsString(s)))
  })
) (unlift(A.unapply))
```

From some reason, when I am trying to write the case class with the following values:

```
A("name", List("val1", "val2"))
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to                             
java.lang.Long
at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
```

It fails on the first case line : case longs: List[Long]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The type parameter of the `List` is erased at runtime, so `longs: List[Long]` will match, no matter what the contained type is. Why do you need a `List[Any]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close, but remember that when you say `List[Any]` it means the list values can be heterogeneous as far as the type system is concerned, and as @m-z points out, the generic types will be erased.

In this situation I'd transform the `List[Any]` into a `List[JsValue]` using `collect` to discard anything that's not either a string or a long:

```
case class A(name: String, values: List[Any])

implicit val myWrites: Writes[A] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "values").write[List[JsValue]].contramap[List[Any]](
    _.collect {
      case str: String => JsString(str)
      case long: Long => JsNumber(long)
    })
)(unlift(A.unapply))
```

I've had to do something similar myself recently for dealing with a web service that accepted heterogeneous JSON arrays, but it's usually a good idea to avoid using `Any` at the Scala level.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion to the solution:

```
implicit val myWrites: Writes[A] = (
(JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "values").write[JsArray].contramap[List[Any]](
    case l if l.isEmpty => JsArray(Seq())
    case list@List(_: Long, _*) => JsArray(list.map(l => JsNumber(l.asInstanceOf[Long])))
    case list@List(_: String, _*) => JsArray(list.map(s => JsString(s.asInstanceOf[String])))
) (unlift(A.unapply))
```

Comment: Be careful with this, since if your list _does_ contain both strings and longs (which the type system will allow) it will fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Agreed -  I assume there won't be several types in the same list.